# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reload' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have this definition of a Datatable defined on a Thymeleaf template of a SpringBoot application, using Datatables

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/   

$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#workerEventTable').dataTable( {
        order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        select: true,
        bLengthChange: false,
        stateSave: true,
        pageLength: 20,
        ajax: 'http://127.0.0.1:1234/acerinox/api/workerevent/datatableList',      
           "columns": [
               { data: 'id' },
               { data: 'deviceId' },
               { data: 'companyName' },
               { data: 'description' },
               { data: 'battery' },
               { data: 'dateTime' },
               { data: 'signal' },           
               { data: 'data' },
               { data: 'alarm' }
           ] 
    });

    setInterval( function () {
        table.ajax.reload( null, false ); // user paging is not reset on reload
    }, 1000 );


    table.on('select.dt deselect.dt', function() {
          localStorage.setItem( 'DataTables_selected', table.rows( { selected: true }).toArray() )   
    })

} );

/*]]>*/
</script>
```

But there is a Javascript problem:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reload' of undefined
```

and this are all the imports I use in the template:

```
<script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"    ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there documentation that suggests that the return value of `dataTable` is an object with an `ajax` property? Because clearly it isn't...

Comment: Add `console.log(table)` to the code to see what the actual properties of `table` are. You can also add a `debugger;` above the failing line to inspect the `table` object, hovering over it, drilling into the properties.

Comment: The problem is that `dataTable()` is returning a jQuery object not a Datatables API.  You will want to use `DataTable()` instead, note the capital `D`.  The first [FAQ](https://datatables.net/faqs/index#Most-common-FAQs) explains this.

Comment: @KThorngren, please convert to answer. It works !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `dataTable()` is returning a jQuery object not a Datatables API. You will want to use `DataTable()` instead, note the capital D. The first [FAQ](https://datatables.net/faqs/index#Most-common-FAQs) explains this.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#workerEventTable').dataTable(...)` does not return an object with an `.ajax` property. If you want to do something after the ajax call completes you could use something like:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": function (data, callback, settings) {
    callback(
      dostuff();
    );
  }
});
```

Have a look at the [documentation of ajax](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax).